# Issue happend while fastly hover on span tag the mouseLeave event is not calling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, rendering, ag-grid

I am trying to change the html element when user enter mouse on the span tag, but if user quickly hover mouse on the element then mouseLeave event is not triggering and thats why checkbox still showing even mouse is not on the element.

here is the code i am trying to do:

```
 <span
      onMouseEnter={() => setHoverId(colId)}}
      onMouseLeave={() => setHoverId(-1)}
    >
      {hoverId === colId || selectionRef.current?.[colId] ? (
        <input
          className="agGrid__customInput"
          ref={(ref: HTMLInputElement | null) => {
            if (!ref) return;
            ref.onclick = (e) => {
              const updatedList = {
                ...selectionRef.current,
                ...(ref.checked && { [colId]: params.data }),
              };
              if (!ref.checked) {
                delete updatedList[colId];
              }
              setSelectionList({ ...updatedList });
              selectionRef.current = { ...updatedList };
              e.stopPropagation();
            };
          }}
          disabled={isSelectionDisabled}
          hidden={disabled}
          type="checkbox"
          defaultChecked={selectionRef.current[colId]}
        />
      ) : (
        <h3>{(params?.rowIndex || 0)+1}</h3>
      )}
    </span>
```